# How to use property within expression?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have a property in my GeoJSON file that is called "bla".

```
"text-field": [
'case',
['!=', ['get', 'bla'], null],
  "{bla}%",
['==', ['get', 'bla'], null],
  " ",
  " ",
],
```

I would like to display that property within a case expression, which is not working.

If I simply pass:

```
"text-field": "{bla}%"
```

it is working just fine.

How do I use properties within that case expression?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use concat instead placeholder:

```
"text-field": [
  "case", ['!=', ['get', 'bla'], null],
    ["concat", ['get', 'bla'], '%'],
  ['==', ['get', 'bla'], null],
    " ",
  " "
]
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/sxma7u68/ ]

Comment: Thanks! In your example it is working but somehow for me it returns nothing, not even the % sign. Any idea why this could happen?

Comment: Found the error, bla has to be a string, integer is not working. Thanks again for your help!